# Refreshing LinQ2SQL Model in Designer without losing all Properties

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, dbml

so I'm using LinQ2SQL quite heavily in my current application, and although I have most stuff in partial classes, some things have to be adjusted in the VS Designer (like Accessors for fields I wrap). Then, sometimes I like to name Fields differently in the Model than they do in the DB.

So, my problem now is. When going back to changing a already known table I have only two options:

- Introduce new fields through the
  designer manually
- Delete the Table from the Model and newly import it from Server Explorer (losing properties)

Both ways are unsatisfactory. Is there some secret button I missed out that says "just refresh changes?" I mean, the model knows all mappings, it can't be that difficult to just get new things from the DB.

Any ways around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022/best-way-to-update-linq-to-sql-classes-after-database-schema-change) question.

Basically this isn't implemented in VS2008. Don't ask me why, maybe the guys at MS were so occupied that they completely forgot about this important feature.