# How do I update a Linq to SQL dbml file?

Tags: linq-to-sql

How do I update a Linq to SQL .dbml file?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

There are three ways to keep the model in sync.

1. Delete the modified tables from the designer, and drag them back onto the designer surface from the Database Explorer.  I have found that, for this to work reliably, you have to:

   a.  Refresh the database schema in the Database Explorer (right-click, refresh)
   b.  Save the designer after deleting the tables
   c.  Save again after dragging the tables back.

   **Note** though that if you have modified any properties (for instance, turning off the child property of an association), this will obviously lose those modifications — you'll have to make them again.
2. Use SQLMetal to regenerate the schema from your database.  I have seen a number of blog posts that show [how to script this](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/petar/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11).
3. Make changes directly in the Properties pane of the DBML.  This works for simple changes, like allowing nulls on a field.

The DBML designer is not installed by default in Visual Studio 2015, 2017 or 2019. You will have to close VS, start the VS installer and modify your installation. The **LINQ to SQL tools** is the feature you must install. For VS 2017/2019, you can find it under *Individual Components > Code Tools*.

Comment: I had tried 1a and 1c without 1b and was getting 'Specified cast is not valid' errors when performing a simple select on a view. Including 1b fixed it for me

Comment: The VS support was requested on ​https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/260723/linq-for-sql-designer-support-for-refresh-resync-of-tables-and-columns, but MS do not want to fix.

Comment: Tried the first method and it worked. Guess it will work for a small DB.

Comment: It pains me that at the end of 2019, I needed an answer created before I knew what computer programming was... This is so detailed and great!

Answer (score 69):

To update a table in your .dbml-diagram with, for example, added columns, do this:

1. Update your SQL Server Explorer window.
2. Drag the "new" version of your table into the .dbml-diagram (report1 in the picture below).

[image: report1 is the new version of the table]

3. Mark the added columns in the new version of the table, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the added columns.

[image: copy the added columns]

4. Click the "old" version of your table and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the added columns into the already present version of the table.

[image: paste the added columns to the old version of the table]

5. Delete the dragged table from step 2 and save the .dbml file.

Comment: This seems to be the easiest, least destructive method that requires no extra tools and works just fine in VS2017

Comment: This is much less intrusive than the accepted answer and continues to work well at the end of 2018!

Comment: This is the best answer for quick (and not-so-quick edits to the schema).  I have taken a lot of time making the model view look nice.  I hated deleting and dragging update files over.  For added fields this works great!

Comment: For me, this solved two problems. The first one was when I attempted to copy and paste a similar field within the table and then rename it. That created non-stop "unspecified" build error when validating. The other issue was that if I removed the table and then added it back in its entirety, it resulted in much larger differences in git (because objects were rearranged within the file). With this method, I only see the insertion of the new field, which is much cleaner and easier to understand later.

Comment: BTW, need to click "Yes" when it prompts you with "The objects you are adding to the designer use a different data connection than the designer..."

Comment: Maybe this is the most reliable and easist way to make it work at vs2019! Thanks.
Actually, I tried using the text editor to make same code as the this way generate, but the vs can't build!!! maybe there is cache or something. Anyway, this works great!

Comment: ...step 5. delete the dragged table from step 2 and save the .dbml.

Answer (score 5):

You could also check out the [PLINQO](http://www.plinqo.com) set of code generation templates, based on CodeSmith, which allow you to do a lot of neat things for and with Linq-to-SQL:

- generate one file per class (instead of a single, huge file)
- update your model as needed
- many more features

Check out the PLINQO site at  http://www.plinqo.com   and have a look at the intro videos.

The second tool I know of are the [Huagati DBML/EDMX tools](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/), which allow update of DBML (Linq-to-SQL) and EDMX (Entity Framework) mapping files, and more (like naming conventions etc.).

Marc

Comment: Having just ripped out CodeSmith / PLINQO I strongly advise **against** taking this approach. Granted this answer is over 4 years old...

Comment: @Yuck: at this point in time, I'd strongly advise against using Linq-to-SQL at all - use Entity Framework instead, much better choice!

Comment: Yes, it is. Moving to EF after verifying that the application would work with a plain DBML instead of PLINQO was the next step I took in dusting off an old application.

Answer (score 4):

We use a custom written T4 template that dynamically queries the information_schema model for each table in all of our .DBML files, and then overwrites parts of the .DBML file with fresh schema info from the database.  I **highly** recommend implementing a solution like this - it has saved me oodles of time, and unlike deleting and re-adding your tables to your model you get to keep your associations.  With this solution, you'll get compile-time errors when your schema changes.  You want to make sure that you're using a version control system though, because diffing is really handy.  This is a great solution that works well if you're developing with a DB schema first approach.  Of course, I can't share my company's code so you're on your own for writing this yourself.  But if you know some Linq-to-XML and can go to school [on this project](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/), you can get to where you want to be.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the visual designer built into VS2008, as updating the dbml also updates the code that is generated for you. Modifying the dbml outside of the visual designer would result in the underlying code being out of sync.

Comment: Yeah, but the visual designer in VS2008 cannot detect and respond to changes in your underlying database :-( Short of deleting and re-adding, there's no support for updating your model :-(

Comment: While that is true, the question was very vague and did not specifically mention how to update a model when the database changes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nuance to updating tables then updating the DBML... Foreign key relationships are not immediately always brought over if changes are made to existing tables. The work around is to do a build of the project and then re-add the tables again. I reported this to MS and its being fixed for VS2010.

[DBML display does not show new foreign key constraints](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=414601)

---

Note that the instructions given in the main answer are not clear. To update the table

1. Open up the dbml design surface
2. Select all tables with Right->Click->Select All or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>
3. <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> (Cut)
4. <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>  (Paste)
5. Save and rebuild solution.

Comment: I don't beleive it's fixed, because related https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/414601/dbml-display-does-not-show-new-foreign-key-constraints#tabs is not fixed

Comment: Do you make your changes before or after you cut and paste?

Comment: It's been 10 years...but I believe that it is before...do the changes then go to #2.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of stored procedure update, you should delete it from the .dbml file and reinsert it again. But if the stored procedure have two paths (ex: if something; display some columns; else display some other columns), make sure the two paths have the same columns aliases!!! Otherwise only the first path columns will exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use Visual Studio 2019 open DBML files in graphic designer to update DBML files.

when not working:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/dbml-files-not-opening-in-graphic-designer-in-vs-2/1659675

Just for the record

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete step-by-step method that worked for me in order to update the LINQ to SQL dbml and associated files to include a new column that I added to one of the database tables.

You need to make the changes to your design surface as suggested by other above; however, you need to do some extra steps. These are the complete steps:

1. Drag your updated table from Server Explorer onto the design surface
2. Copy the new column from this "new" table to the "old" table (see M463 answer for details on this step)
3. Delete the "new" table that you just dragged over
4. Click and highlight the stored procedure, then delete it
5. Drag the new stored procedure and drop into place.
6. Delete the .designer.vb file in the code-behind of the .dbml
   (if you do not delete this, your code-behind containing the schema will
   not update even if you rebuild and the new table field will not be included)
7. Clean and Rebuild the solution (this will rebuild the .designer.vb file to include all the new changes!).