# Visual Studio Tool to update a DBML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update Linq to SQL dbml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110171/how-to-update-linq-to-sql-dbml-file)

Is there a quick command in VS2008 to update a DBML that I'm missing or do I have to dleete everything, re-add and then deal with renames and table mods manually? This seems a bit tedious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DBML so LINQ to SQL; you can delete and re-add a table as one option; that's what we do in our app... curious if there is a better way, but this works quick so that's what we do.  THe drop down in the properties window is a quick selector for the table, and we delete, and then bring in the changed table, and it recreates the fields/relationships.

THere isn't an update model from DB like in ADO.NET entity framework.