# Update Linq2SQL .dbml from .designer.cs

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is there an easy and/or automated way to update a Linq2SQL .dbml file from the .designer.cs file? One of our new-hires is still pretty new to .NET/Linq and updated the .designer.cs directly by hand. The "Run Custom Tool" option doesn't work; it updates .designer.cs from .dbml (backwards from what I want).

Comment: Could you re-create the database from designer and then get it back into DBML with SQLMetal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update Linq to SQL dbml file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110171/how-to-update-linq-to-sql-dbml-file)