# LinqToSQL DBML files doesn't detect changes in underlying database (still not fixed in VS2010)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

There are several old (around 2009) questions on SO addressing this issue, for example:

[How do I update a Linq to SQL dbml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110171/how-to-update-linq-to-sql-dbml-file)

**Just to confirm**, is it still the case that VS2010 does not (and can not) automatically update LinqToSQL DBML files when a schema change occurs in the underlying database?  So one must still either delete all tables from the existing DBML diagram and re-add, or use one of the 3rd party offerings to do the code generation, is this correct??

(If so, recommendations on the latest/greatest 3rd party tool, including price, would likely  be helpful to others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. Entity Framework supports this though.

If you're sticking to LINQ to SQL, this tool does what you want: http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/