# How to update linq2sql model?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, orm

I have 2 projects which use the same database. If I change database structure for first project, how can I update linq2sql model in my second project?

every time delete and recreate all objects? can I syncronize my model with database?

Answer (score 2):

There is no out-of-the box synchronization for Linq-2-sql. There are some third party products that will do this for you. Look here [How do I update a Linq to SQL dbml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1110171/532498)

However, have you considered moving the data layer to a separate class library and reference that in both projects? That way you are always consistent.