# Detect changes in LINQ TO SQL O/R Designer

Tags: database, linq-to-sql, designer

I am using LINQ TO SQL O/R Designer to map my database tables to Entities class to create a model, I have 3 questions:

Q1: If a database connection is changed, how to refresh the model?

Q2: If table and/or Stored Procedure is changed, how to refresh w/out delete & drop these objects into O/R designer?

Q3: Is there a way to detect if a model has been changed?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update Linq to SQL dbml file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110171/how-to-update-linq-to-sql-dbml-file)

Answer (score 0):

no. there is only way to delete them from dbml and again drag changed entities or stored procedures from server explorer. there is no sync update for dbml that can automatically detect sql database changes.