# Linq Sql Database Context MissingMethod

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I originally had a project that I use as a connection to my database but the issue is that when I added a new table that I just created to the dbml file via dragging the table from Server Explorer it seems to work but doesn't. Instead it just throws an error.

**Code**

```
 PIMDataContext dbContext = new PIMDataContext();
        foreach (var thing in dbContext.Product_NewProduct_Xrefs)
            Console.WriteLine(thing.ProductNumber);
        Console.Read();
```

PIM.dbml (the dbml I edited also the dbml the context above refers to)

[image]

And finally here is the error

```
Method not found: 'System.Data.Linq.Table`1<PIM_DATA.Product_NewProduct_Xref> PIM_DATA.PIMDataContext.get_Product_NewProduct_Xrefs()'.
```

What I checked already,

- Rebuild
- Restart VS2012
- Re-Import Database project
- Delete References and Re-add references

Comment: did you Refresh it ..? also I recall VS having an issue with this do you have a backup of the original one.. when you add it it removes from what I can remember 2 or 3 using statements from the hear in the .cs file .. read this link as well for the steps to `Refresh .dbml` file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110171/how-to-update-linq-to-sql-dbml-file

Comment: Well I added a whole table to the dbml file so I see no reason why it wouldn't refresh. I just set a property to nullable and saved rebuilt and renulled it then rebuilt and still same error as well

Comment: Is it possible the database project is not really getting rebuilt? Or that its getting rebuilt in debug configuration, and your main project references the Release dll?

Comment: Try to find out who calls get_Product_NewProduct_Xrefs, I do not think linq2sql should generate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up deleting the whole connection to db. Re-inputing the connection details and recreating the whole dbml file.