# Linq To Sql Not recognizing changes to database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Something happened to some of the files in my visual studio project so I had to transfer the working files to a new project.

Everything is working fine except when I try to add new stuff to my database (like a new column) linq to sql does not recognize the changes.

At one point (I think when I opened up the dbml file) something popped up on visual studio saying something to the effect, that the link to the database (I am not sure if it mentioned web.config) is incorrect so they are just going to use the link in the dbml file (or something like that).

How do I get the correct link? and where do I put it?

So linq to sql will recognize changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on any white space on your ".DBML" file and then go to properties option. You'll be able to find the "Conexión(Connection)" option in where there'll be listed all your SQL connections, just pick one and that's it.
Once you have this done Visual Studio will recognize your future changes.

[image: Optionss]

Note: This will help you to establish or change the connection with your SQL server. If you want to update your DBML scheme you can read this:  [How do I update a Linq to SQL dbml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110171/how-do-i-update-a-linq-to-sql-dbml-file)