# How to resolve CS1061 Data Context Does not contain a reference to a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to revise an ASP.NET C# Web Forms application. The Linq-to-SQL designer already has tables mapped and the data context already had been created. I've added several stored procedures to the database, and added them by dragging from Server Explorer onto the methods pane of the O/R designer.

In my code behind page, I've written the following code to call my stored procedure:

```
private void RunResponses(int iStudyID )
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt = GetResponses(iStudyID);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        gvStudyResponseData.DataSource = dt;
        gvStudyResponseData.DataBind();
        // Session["dtAnalysisReport"] = dt;
    }
    else   // No records then create a dummy record to make Gridview still show up...
    {
        gvStudyResponseData.DataSource = null;
        gvStudyResponseData.DataBind();
    }
}

private DataTable GetResponses(int iStudyID)
{
    //string sSQL = "";
    //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL"].ConnectionString);
    //DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //sSQL = "EXEC spGetAnalysisReport @StudyID=" + iStudyID.ToString();
    //Debug.WriteLine(sSQL);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (PROTOTYPING db = new PROTOTYPING(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            gvStudyResponseData.DataSource = db.spGetAnalysisReport(iStudyID);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            dt.Dispose();
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```

My intent is to call `RunResponses` on `Page_Load`, so that the data for a given `StudyID` is hydrating a `gvStudyResponseData` gridview. PROTOTYPING is the data context automatically generated by the Linq-to-SQL designer.

The full error is

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'PROTOTYPING' does not contain a definition for 'spGetAnalysisReport' and no extension method 'spGetAnalysisReport' accepting a first argument of type 'PROTOTYPING' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I ensure that the `spGetAnalysisReport` stored procedure is properly called by the code behind and that it is adequately mapped to the stored procedure in the database?

Comment: Your problem is a little bit unclear, can you provide exact CS1061 message and is that error occurred when calling `gvStudyResponseData.DataSource = db.spGetAnalysisReport(iStudyID);`?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Error message is now included. The error occurs on the line you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: I believe you have reference issue when calling that SP with `PROTOTYPING` context, check if namespace provided by designer.cs file (which included in same folder with DBML) referenced properly and `spGetAnalysisReport` exists there.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto It turns out that the Prototyping.designer.cs does not contain an implementation of spGetAnalysisReport. If I manually add an entry to this designer, wont future updates potentially overwrite it?

Comment: Are you want to update existing DBML file which includes `spGetAnalysisReport` procedure then? Check this reference for LINQ to SQL DBML update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110171/how-do-i-update-a-linq-to-sql-dbml-file.