# How to use LINQ to SQL after changes in database

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

**Note:**

I know there was disscussion about similar questions before, like in:

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022/best-way-to-update-linq-to-sql-classes-after-database-schema-change)

but i have to know how to handle this scenario:

**Problem:**

I wrote program that use LINQ to SQL and it will be send to client. Tables that my program uses may be changed ( let's say only added new columns). Is there any way to not update, recompile and send my program to client each time those changes occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, because linq to sql classes map your database into objects, and when you change database, model classes do not reflect real database.